# Using Date parameter in SQL query, ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

I am writing a code that calls a column from a dataset using a SQL query. I use two parameters to identify which rows to select. One is the ProductSerialNumber, and the other is a datetimestamp. See my SQL query below

```
    Select TestStation FROM tblData
    WHERE ProductSerialNumber = ? AND Datetimestamp = ?
```

In the dataset's datatable the productserialnumber is formatted as text, and the other is formatted as a date (as you would expect).

In my vb.net code, I grab the Datetimestamp from another source (don't ask why, the only thing you need to know is that it grabs a valid datetimestamp, dimensioned as a date, that matches exactly with the tblData's entry) and I use the premade query to generate a datatable. The query is a Fill query called "TestStationLookUp"

my vb.net code looks like this

```
    Dim dt as new dataset.tbldataDataTable
    Dim dta As New DataSetTableAdapters.tbldataTableAdapter
    Dim ProductSerialNumber as string = "XXXXXX"
    Dim DateTimeStamp as date = SomeDateVariable
    dta.TestStationLookUp(dt, ProductSerialNumber, DateTimeStamp)
```

It is here that the code tells me:

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. 

       Line 7366:                dataTable.Clear
       Line 7367:            End If
Error: Line 7368:            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
       Line 7369:            Return returnValue
       Line 7370:        End Function
```

I cannot understand why this error arises, as everything is dimensioned the way it should be. This exact code setup works elsewhere in my code (except it doesn't use a date), but this specific piece won't work.

Also, if I go to the dataset in my solution, I can use the "preview data" on this query and type in the EXACT same parameters    (the ProductSerialNumber and DateTimeStamp that match the record in the table AND what I use in my vb code) and it will give me produce the table I want.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your comment.

dta.TestStationLookUp is the TableAdapter's query. I provided the query code above (I just changed the name of things for confidential reasons)

Comment: What if you increase the size of your field? What size do you currently have it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to access not valid unique id "ProductSerialNumber", maybe it does not exist

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Instead of passing the variable that comes from dataset ,pass a valid number that you are sure it exists in database